# Divergence theorem with a hemisphere

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, calculus

> 10. State the divergence theorem. Describe the regions over which the integrations are carried out and the quantities that are being integrated.
>
> Consider the vector field $$\mathbf{V}=\frac{3y\mathbf{i}+2xz\mathbf{j}-z\mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.$$ Find the outward flux across the boundary of the hemispherical volume bounded from below by the spherical surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ (for $z<0$) and from above by the $x-y$ plane.
>
> Use the divergence theorem to verify the result.

My attempt at the question involved me using the divergence theorem as follows:

$${\large\bigcirc}\kern{-1.55 em}\iint\limits_{S}\vec{\mathbf{F}}\cdot d\vec{\mathbf{S}}=\iiint\limits_{D}\text{div}(\vec{\mathbf{F}})\,dV$$

By integrating using spherical coordinates it seems to suggest the answer is $-\frac{2}{3}\pi R^2$. We would expect the same for the LHS. My calculation for the flat section of the hemisphere is zero while the curved surface is $-\pi R^2$.

Therefore it appears that the RHS and LHS do not agree but I'm unsure what went wrong. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: -1. You are not asking a conceptual question about physics. You are only asking for help with your homework  exercises. This is not a homework help site.

Comment: Hi David and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).